# How to make my list of enemies to shot c#

Tags: c#

I've been working on some game project for college work. My problem is that I have list of enemies that is moving left-right and when touching left or right edge goes down a bit, and what i want them to do is to shot bullets from random enemy while game lasts,but I have managed for bullet to show and shot from random enemy but that is it :'D, it just goes that one time and it needs to go while game lasts. So here is my method for shooting to me it looks all right and cant figure  out why is just one shot.
I'm beginner so sorry if my code looks stupid.

```
private int MoveEnemyBullet()
    {
        int randomnum = r.Next(30);
        shooter = enemies[randomnum];
        bullet.Goto_Sprite(shooter);
        bulletEnemy.Add(bullet);
        bullet.SetVisible(true);
        bullet.Active = true;
        while (START)
        {
            if(bulletEnemy.Count!=0)

               bullet.Y += bullet.speed;
            Wait(0.01);
            if (bullet.TouchingEdge())
            {
                bullet.SetVisible(false);
           
               
            }
            
       
        }
        Game.StartScript(MoveEnemyBullet);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is hard to read since there is only a little of it. What is bullet, bulletEnemy or START? I would ask why you don't have a list of bullets also, but i think that you want to only have one bullet at a time on the screen.

There might be a problem with TouchingEdge() method. Something similar happened to me, the bullet was not destroyed when it whent out of the bounds of the screen, only when it hit its target, so the bullet was still "alive" but outside the screen, still moving. If this happened to you, the bullet was never set to invisible.

Also, it does not seem to me that you change the value of START, which would mean that your while loop never ends. If you change it to false in the SetVisible(false) method, then this is not the problem.

I believe Goto_Sprite(shooter) changes the position of the bullet to the new shooter, but you should check if that one is correct too.